# Why would a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_connect block whole thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, c++11, boost

Actually this will be now almost two weeks I've been figuring out this problem, and I finally at least know possible cause. What happens is, that a call to `socket::async_connect` blocks the thread and seemingly acts as *synchronous*. The call looks like bellow and happens in :

```
void Layer104::connect(const std::string& ip, const std::string& port)
{
  try
  {
    tcp::resolver resolver(io);
    tcp::resolver::query query(ip.c_str(), port.c_str());
    tcp::resolver::iterator it = resolver.resolve(query);  

    LOGMTRTTIDEBUG("StartProtocol()"<<endl);
    activeSocket->async_connect(*it, boost::bind(&LayerXXX::connectHandler, getPtr(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    LOGMTRTTIDEBUG("StartProtocol() started using activeSocket->async_connect."<<endl);
  }
  catch (exception&)
  {
    LOGMTRTTIERR("ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED"<<endl)
    handleError(ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED);
  }  
}
```

As you can see I have two debug messages there to see if the function returned. 90% the function returns immediatelly and I get this in the log:

```
  Date                     Thread name                 Thread id  Method name                    Message
D 2015-11-02 10:35:39:787 [Client 192.168.8.23:1242        #6576] MyProtocol::LayerXXX::connect StartProtocol()
D 2015-11-02 10:35:39:788 [Client 192.168.8.23:1242        #6576] MyProtocol::LayerXXX::connect StartProtocol() started using activeSocket->async_connect.
```

But sometimes, and this **only happens when network connection is very bad**, I just see this, last message from that thread at all:

```
  Date                     Thread name   ID     Method name                   Message
D 2015-11-02 10:35:39:787 [Client        #6576] MyProtocol::LayerXXX::connect StartProtocol()
```

And since then the thread is stuck here:

[image: image description]

The thread I'm talking about is using the `boost::asio::io_service` event loop and also the `connect` method is called from this event loop. This is how the thread is started:

```
void MyClient::threadMain() {
    LOGMTRTTIDEBUG("Starting boost::asio::io_service main loop."<<endl);
    // IP and port is added to name after connecting succesfully
    ThreadNameMap::setName( "Client" );
    io_.run();
    LOGMTRTTIDEBUG("boost::asio::io_service main OVER! Thread DEAD!"<<endl);
}
```

The relevant stacktrace when the thread is stuck:

```
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject()  + 0xa bytes  
mswsock.dll!__GSHandlerCheck_SEH()  + 0x2c95 bytes  
mswsock.dll!__GSHandlerCheck_SEH()  + 0x5e0c bytes  
ws2_32.dll!WSAAccept()  + 0xd4 bytes    
ws2_32.dll!accept()  + 0x15 bytes   
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::call_accept<int>(int * __formal, unsigned __int64 s, sockaddr * addr, unsigned __int64 * addrlen)  Line 96 + 0x32 bytes   C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::accept(unsigned __int64 s, sockaddr * addr, unsigned __int64 * addrlen, boost::system::error_code & ec)  Line 114 + 0x19 bytes    C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::socket_select_interrupter::open_descriptors()  Line 90 + 0x1c bytes   C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::socket_select_interrupter::socket_select_interrupter()  Line 42   C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::select_reactor::select_reactor(boost::asio::io_service & io_service)  Line 48 + 0x86 bytes    C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::select_reactor>(boost::asio::io_service & owner)  Line 81 + 0x26 bytes  C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(const boost::asio::io_service::service::key & key, boost::asio::io_service::service * (boost::asio::io_service &)* factory)  Line 123 + 0x13 bytes   C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::select_reactor>()  Line 49 C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::select_reactor>(boost::asio::io_service & ios)  Line 34  C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::get_reactor()  Line 620 + 0xd bytes C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::start_connect_op(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type & impl, boost::asio::detail::reactor_op * op, const sockaddr * addr, unsigned __int64 addrlen)  Line 550 + 0xd bytes   C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::async_connect<boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,MyProtocol::LayerXXX,boost::system::error_code const & __ptr64>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<MyProtocol::LayerXXX * __ptr64>,boost::arg<1> > > >(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::implementation_type & impl, const boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> & peer_endpoint, boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,MyProtocol::LayerXXX,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<MyProtocol::LayerXXX *>,boost::arg<1> > > & handler)  Line 515  C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::async_connect<boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,MyProtocol::LayerXXX,boost::system::error_code const & __ptr64>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<MyProtocol::LayerXXX * __ptr64>,boost::arg<1> > > >(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::implementation_type & impl, const boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> & peer_endpoint, const boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,MyProtocol::LayerXXX,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<MyProtocol::LayerXXX *>,boost::arg<1> > > & handler)  Line 234  C++
myapp64d.exe!boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::async_connect<boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,MyProtocol::LayerXXX,boost::system::error_code const & __ptr64>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<MyProtocol::LayerXXX * __ptr64>,boost::arg<1> > > >(const boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> & peer_endpoint, const boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,MyProtocol::LayerXXX,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<MyProtocol::LayerXXX *>,boost::arg<1> > > & handler)  Line 779 C++
myapp64d.exe!MyProtocol::LayerXXX::connect(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & ip, const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & port)  Line 225    C++     ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject()  + 0xa bytes
```

What I know so far:

1. This only happens when network is **dropping** packets, so it must be timing related. I simulated this using [clumsy 0.2](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/) (recommended).
2. `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_connect` is called from `boost::asio::io_service` event loop, but it works most of the time
3. According to bug reports we've got, this thread doesn't go un-stuck in any reasonable amount of time. So it's not like some timeout... and anyway, the connect should be asynchronous.

We have this issue on our production systems, I'm really looking for any hints that could help us find a lead to fix/workaround this behaviour.

Comment: So, `select` return that there is new connection, then boost call `accept`, but instead of instantly return `accept` blocks. What about other platforms, is this bug reproducible on linux?

Comment: @user1034749 I don't know, although the software is compilable on linux (or others say so) nobody uses it on that platform. I don't even claim this is a boost bug, but whatever it is, I need some workaround for it. And if I find the cause, I think boost developers might be interested in knowing about that too.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a SSCCE? Also, you should at say on what platform you reproduce it. Consider dropping the question on the boost mailing list (once you have it reduced). Once these are there, I'll either find it myself or bounty the question. It looks really interesting

Comment: It seems that somehow the socket has not been set non-blocking. The only way to ensure that a socket operation does not block is to use a non-blocking operation.

Comment: Looking into the asio code (I currently only have 1.55), this has nothing to do with your main `async_connect` operation - and seems to be related to the internal socket that asio sets up for interrupt handling. The operations on this socket are *synchronous* (see the code in: asio/detail/impl/socket_select_interrupter.ipp: 90) Normally this sequence should be good (sets up server listen, call client connect, then call server accept) except in your cases where it fails.. though not sure why this is failing (not a windows guy, so don't know what the cases could be..)

Comment: ...it's only after the accept completes, both sockets are set to non-blocking..

Comment: @sehe The problem is that this is a big application and I don't even really understand the code I'm debugging. So I don't know how ton reproduce it. I will try to make a simple socket client program, but I think it might be related not only to OS, but also the servers we're connecting to. And these are not gonna be accessible for anyone anytime soon.

Comment: @sehe I am working on simple client program to see whther it reproduces the issue, but I have strong doubts about it.

Comment: @sehe I was able to reproduce this on Windows 7 with this code: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp and the use of clumsy.

Comment: Any progress, do you report your findings to boost people?

Comment: @user1034749 Although I was able to reproduce the issue, I also found out it's not the reason for deadlock in our program. As such, further research was not priority. I have a suspicion this may indeed be a windows issue related to the `clumsy` program I used. It might be also a boost issue of course. All you need to find out is to write native equivalent of the program I posted in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: Exclude the 127.0.0.1 in clumsy filter.**

I meet the same problem while using boost `async_connect` with clumsy, even I'm just using the UDP socket. I found the problem was caused by clumsy Filtering, if the filtering address include the `127.0.0.1` (etc, outbound and ip.DstAddr >= 127.0.0.1 and ip.DstAddr <= 239.255.255.255), the problem will happen frequetly, and if not, the problem disappeared. So I look into the code of boost `async_connect`, found that it call `::accept` in `127.0.0.1` in function `open_descriptors`, which will block if network packats droped.